# Adding to a series within a List in Java

Tags: java, list, time-series, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to do some graphing. One of the classes for managing your data is `TimeSeries`. There is also a class `TimeSeriesCollection` which has a `List` of `TimeSeries` in it.

`TimeSeries` has a method `add()` that makes it easy to throw a new datapoint at the end, whereas `TimeSeriesCollection` does not. I wanted to add a method into `TimeSeriesCollection` that would call the `add()` function for each of its TimeSeries, however, I'm not very familiar working with Lists in Java.

From what I've seen, one possible method would be to `get()` each `TimeSeries`, call it's `add()` method, and then `set()` it back into the List. But this seems pretty inefficient. Is it possible to directly call methods of elements within a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to call the add method for every TimeSeries:

```
for (TimeSeries timeSeries: TimeSeriesCollection.timeSeriesList) {
  timeSeries.add(datapoint);
}
```

You don't even have to set the objects, you modify back into the list in TimeSeriesCollection, because you don't create a copy of the elements. You are directly modifying the object references in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could do this with Lists.